# Azure web app - syncing files from external process

Tags: azure-web-app-service, batch-processing

This question feels so simple that I'm confused why I can't find an answer!

We have an Azure web app, typically running on 2 to 5 instances.

At the moment we manually run a quite intensive PHP script a few times a day on a local computer to generate a folder of files. (The resulting folder isn't huge - typically about 10MB in size and a few hundred files in total.) We then sync them via Github and they deploy to the website. Easy.

That process is fine, but we want to move the PHP script to Azure so we can remove the dependency on running it locally and instead run it as a chron job.

How can we reliably sync the outputted folder from our script into our web app?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by *sync them via Github*? Are you deploying from  source control? Does your script produce the **entirety** of what needs to go in your `wwwroot` folder, or does it just add additional file to some base deployment?

Comment: Hi David, yes, we deploy via Github (and hence any given file might be created, updated, deleted, or left as-is).The script doesn't produce the entirety of the site, just the `wwwroot/json-data` folder (which is then used by other code on the server).

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use a triggered WebJob with a cron schedule. Your WebJob can contain just your PHP script. Or if it needs a special command line to run, include a `run.cmd` batch file with the full PHP command line.

In your PHP script, do whatever you need to gather the right set of files, and then just copy them to `%home%\site\wwwroot\json-data`.

For this to work, everything you need to do within your PHP script needs to be runnable within the App Service sandbox. You should first try this directly from Kudu Console before moving it to a WebJob, to make sure everything can run.

Comment: I know WebJobs run on each instance, but presumably this would rerun the entire PHP script on each instance (which wouldn't work, because the script interacts with web services, which change each time they are accessed). Would it make more sense to run it somewhere else and push it to, say, Azure Blob Storage, and use a continuous WebJob to copy the Azure Storage files to each webapp instance?

Comment: Only Continuous WebJobs run on each instance. Scheduled WebJobs (using `settings.job` from the cron) only run on one instance. Also, note that all instances on an app share the same file system, so there is no need to do the copying on each instance. Doing it an an arbitrary instance (where the cron runs) will make it go to all of them.

Comment: That's great to know! Thanks David!

Answer (score 0):

Set your web app deployment source to Local Git. After that push your code to WebApp by Git Push . I am not sure about PHP build process but when you push your code to AzureWeb app via LocalGit method it builds and restores all dependencies and deploy it . For custom build script you can refer https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Custom-Deployment-Script.
https://medium.com/@trstringer/custom-build-logic-post-git-push-with-azure-app-service-and-kudu-for-a-node-js-web-app-1b2719598916